Mongoose and MongoDB: Handling Date Fields and Avoiding Crashes When Updating DueDates
I'm working on a Node.js application using Express, Mongoose, and MongoDB. My application includes a feature where task due dates are automatically refreshed every 24 hours. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to update these dates in MongoDB, and my application crashes.
Task.js(Model)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    dueDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    assignedTo: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    
})

taskControllers.js
const updateDueDate = async (req, res) => {
    const { dueDate } = req.body;

    if (!dueDate || isNaN(new Date(dueDate).getTime())) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid due date' });
    }
    try {
        const tasks = await Task.find({});
        await Promise.all(tasks.map(async (task) => {
            task.dueDate = new Date(dueDate);
            await task.save();
        }).catch(err => {
            return res.status(400).json({ err: err.message });
        }));

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Duedates updated });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error updating due dates:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating duedates', error: err.message });
    }
};

TaskDetails.js

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/users/{user.id}/tasks'); 
        setDailyTasks(response.data.tasks);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tasks:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchTasks();
  }, [setDailyTasks]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const refreshDueDate = async () => {
      const newDueDate = new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
      try {
        const response = await axios.put(`/api/tasks/due`, { dueDate: newDueDate });
        setDailyTasks(prevTasks => prevTasks.map(task => ({
          ...task,
          dueDate: newDueDate,
        })));
        console.log('Duedate updated!', response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating duedate', error);
      }
    };
 
    const interval = setInterval(refreshDueDate, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    refreshDueDate();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [setDailyTasks]);


When I attempt to update the due dates, I encounter errors and the application crashes. Specifically, I'm seeing the following error in my logs:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
MongoError: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
Questions
How can I ensure that the dates are correctly formatted and saved in MongoDB without causing the application to crash?
Is there a better way to handle date updates to avoid issues with BSON date format?
Are there any best practices for managing date fields in Mongoose and MongoDB that I'm missing?
What I've Tried
Ensuring the dueDate field is correctly defined as a Date type in the Mongoose schema.
Formatting the date as an ISO string before sending it to the backend.
Adding detailed error logging to identify where the process fails.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Unexpected end of JSON input means that there is either no data, or malformed data. So please check the format of the dueDate wheather it is in the correct format as defined in your schema before attempting to update it into DB.

I have checked that it seems to save like this "2024-06-12T17:39:00.000Z" . I am not sure if I am sending that correctly, what do you think?
